# Getting error 401 unauthorized while deploying to Nexus from Jenkins. How to solve it?

Tags: maven, jenkins, devops, nexus

I am gettings build failure in jenkins while deploying to nexus?????

also settings.xml file, don't know how error 401 coming

How to solve error 401 unauthorized? what's wrong with my nexus server? how to successfully deploy files to nexus server.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXgrY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the nexus error 401 unauthorized is quite generic and could mean several things. Based on my experience, I will share the things that I usually check when I face this issue.

First of all, I would advice to run this maven command in the agent to understand what credentials are being used during this build:

```
mvn help:effective-settings -DshowPasswords=true
```

This will give a pretty good understanding of the credentials involved.

Later, you need to check:

1. **User without proper grants to push to nexus.** You need to make sure that the user that you are using in Jenkins has proper access that allows use Nexus with read and write permissions.
2. **pom.xml repo id**: In the distributionManagement section, you probably have one repo for snapshots and another for releases. You need to specific them with a specific id.
3. **settings.xml in Jenkins**: Also, you need to set up the Jenkins file to use the proper credentials for the specific id of above point. In order to do that, you can access next address in your Jenkins:

   https://yourJenkinsInstace/manage/configfiles/editConfig?id=maven-settings

It should looks like this:

[image: Jenkins settings.xml]

4. **Release version can't be pushed twice** Last thing to keep in mind is that you are pushing the release version 1.0, if this version it is already in the nexus, you will get the same message you are getting. Only SNAPSHOT version can be build as many times as you wish.

Let me know if you managed to solve the issue after checking those points.

Comment: Again faied consol output:-   [INFO] --- deploy:3.1.0:deploy (default-deploy) @ maven-enterprise-application ---
Uploading to nexus: http://54.238.147.225:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/mt/maven-enterprise-application/1.0/maven-enterprise-application-1.0.pom
Progress (1): 1.4 kB.

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.0:deploy (default-deploy) on project maven-enterprise-application: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.mt:maven-enterprise-application:pom:1.0 from/to nexus (http://54.238.147.225:8081/repository/maven-releases/): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401) -> [Help 1]

Comment: my distribution tag:- <distributionManagement>
 
     <repository>
       <id>nexus</id>
       <name>Mithun Technologies Releases Nexus Repository</name>
       <url>http://54.238.147.225:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
     </repository>
     
     <snapshotRepository>
       <id>nexus</id>
       <name>Mithun Technologies Snapshot Nexus Repository </name>
       <url>http://54.238.147.225:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
     </snapshotRepository>
     
 </distributionManagement>

Comment: my settings.xml tags:- <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>**********</password>
    </server>